# Exposing an extra header to userspace in the Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, header

I've been maintaining a local patch to the Linux-4.9 Kernel for a piece of research. The patch adds three system calls. The system calls are *not* suitable for upstreaming.

Until now I've used `make deb-pkg` to generate Debian packages for my kernel. Once installed, userspace can call the new system calls using `syscall(2)` to one of the `__NR_...` macros generated by the build process.

The problem I want to solve is: the header that defines the syscall numbers is in the `libc-dev` package generated by `make deb-pkg`. Installing a custom `libc-dev` causes havoc for `apt-get` (last time I installed my custom `libc-dev`, it uninstalled all of llvm and gcc, and rendered `apt-get` unusable with some odd "held packages" scenario that I don't understand (despite `dpkg --get-selections` showing no held packages)).

What I'd like to do is ship a header of my own crafting with the kernel headers, thus avoiding the dreaded `libc-dev` package altogether.

My patch adds a `krun` directory to the top-level of the kernel source dir:

```
$ find krun
krun
krun/test_prog
krun/Makefile
krun/test_prog.c
krun/krun_reg.h
krun/.gitignore
krun/krun-kernel.h
krun/krun.c
```

From reading the [Linux-4.9 Kernel Docs](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) it seems I should be able to expose `krun-kernel.h` using `header-y`.

So `krun/Makefile` looks like this:

```
obj-y := krun.o
header-y += krun-kernel.h

test_prog: test_prog.c
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -o $@ $<
clean:
        rm -f test_prog
```

and in the top-level Makefile, I have:

```
core-y          += krun/                                                        
header-y        += krun/
```

However, if I run:

```
$ make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=./tmp_hdrs
```

My header is nowhere to be seen under `tmp_hdrs`.

Is this possible somehow? Thanks.

Comment: It works if I put my header in `include/uapi/linux` and add an entry to the `Kbuild` file in that directory. Perhaps you can't install headers from directories not under `include`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt to answer my own question.

With Kbuild, it appears you can do two things WRT headers:

- Expose them to userspace and have them packaged into `libc-dev`.
- Have them installed as kernel headers, which cannot be included by userspace.

So what I am asking cannot be done.

The best solution for me is (sadly) to manually copy the header into the system's include directory.